# OpenCv - Memory leak when capturing frames from webcam

Tags: c++, c, opencv, memory-leaks, gtk

I am writing a C application that captures images from a webcam using OpenCv, then saves the images to a file. It is running on Raspian OS Wheezy against OpenCv 2.3.1-11.

If I just open and close the webcam like so, there is no memory leak, so I don't think I'm encountering an older bug about a "webcam opening tax":

```
CvCapture* capture;
while (1) {
  // No increase in memory consumption at all
  capture = cvCreateCameraCapture(0);
  cvReleaseCapture(&capture);
}
```

However, when I actually start acquiring images, memory consumption explodes, and every iteration chews up another 2MB in memory. I've confirmed via `free -s 2` at the command line while manually triggering image acquisition, and noticing that eventually, my application complains about not having enough memory to acquire images.

```
capture = cvCreateCameraCapture(0);
while (1) {
   if (capture) {
      frame = cvQueryFrame(capture);
   }
   if (frame) {
      CvSize size = cvSize(100, 100);
      tmp = cvCreateImage(size, IPL_DEPTH_8U, 3);
      cvResize(frame, tmp, CV_INTER_CUBIC);
      // Do some stuff with tmp
   }
}
cvReleaseCapture(&capture);
```

I've checked various posts online, and it says I'm not support to modify the data stored in `frame`. If I use `cvReleaseImage` on `frame`, it has no effect. In fact, memory usage explodes just from the `cvQueryFrame` call alone. Even the following example below causes this issue to pop up:

```
capture = cvCreateCameraCapture(0);
while (1) {
   if (capture) {
      frame = cvQueryFrame(capture);
   }
}
cvReleaseCapture(&capture);
```

How do I go about resolving this?

Do I truly have to go with the C++ API (not really a choice for me at the moment), or is there some other way about this? This is a Gtk+-2.0 application, and the only headers I'm including are:

```
/*******************************************************************************
 * Preprocessor Directives
 ******************************************************************************/
#include "opencv/cxcore.h"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui_c.h"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc_c.h"

#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <gdk-pixbuf/gdk-pixbuf.h>
```

There is a mix of `opencv` and `opencv2` in there it would seem, but I can't find a way to have just `opencv` headers and have access to the camera without them. I was concerned maybe this is causing certain pieces of C++-only code to be initialized in an undefined manner. Any help in resolving the memory leak or, if need be, creating the equivalent code in C++ without the leak would be very helpful.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: `cvReleaseImage on frame, it has no effect`  How do you know it has no effect?  If you're using Task Manager or some other OS tool to determine if memory is leaked, don't use it.  Using such tools will not determine memory leakage.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Regardless of how well those tools may or may not work, if I monitor the output of `free -s 2` on the console, I see total available system memory drop each time I manually trigger another image acquisition. I can also profile the application and confirm it's chewing up more memory.

Comment: Is `tmp` ever released?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Yes, `tmp` is eventually released via a separate function that just calls `cvReleaseImage(IplImage** imgToFree)`. I have also added another example of just calling `cvQueryFrame` causing the same issue. Thanks!

Comment: can you try to remove all the headers and just use `#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>`?

Comment: **Update:**This behavior does not appear when running this code directly in `main()`, but when running in a separate `pthread` which goes to sleep every 2 seconds, the issue appears.

Comment: is your thread interrupted/canceled/restarted/modified without releasing tmp etc?

Comment: @Micka No, sadly. I just figured out what was causing it, but will be marking yours as accepted since it helped resolve the issue. Thanks!

Comment: good to hear that it helped =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After considerable testing, it turns out that OpenCv 2.3.1-11 has some wonky behavior when working with `pthread`s.

If I just use the following in a loop in `main()`, no issues.

```
int main()
{
    CvCapture* capture;
    IplImage* frame;
    IplImage* tmp;

    capture = cvCreateCameraCapture(0);
    while (1) {
       if (capture) {
          frame = cvQueryFrame(capture);
       }
       if (frame) {
          CvSize size = cvSize(100, 100);
          tmp = cvCreateImage(size, IPL_DEPTH_8U, 3);
          cvResize(frame, tmp, CV_INTER_CUBIC);
          // Do some stuff with tmp

          // release tmp:
          cvReleaseImage(&tmp);
       }
    }
    cvReleaseCapture(&capture);
}
```

If I use the same loop in a `pthread`, it will cause at least 2MB of memory loss per iteration. However, if, in a `pthread`, I only call `capture = cvCreateCameraCapture(0)` and `cvReleaseCapture(&capture)` once, the issue is no longer present.

Also, if I call `cvCreateCameraCapture(0)` in main and assign it to something accessible from the thread (ie: a global variable, or storing it in a context variable that I pass a pointer of to the thread when I spawn the thread), I get the memory leak behavior on every call within the `pthread` to `cvQueryFrame()`.

So, in short, if using the C API (deprecated, I know) in a multi-threaded program, there is a multitude of ways in which you can shoot yourself in the foot. Thank you all for your input.

Answer (score 1):

This one doesnt leak for me:

```
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
int main()
{
    CvCapture* capture;
    IplImage* frame;

    capture = cvCreateCameraCapture(0);
    while (1) 
    {
       if (capture) 
       {
          frame = cvQueryFrame(capture);
       }
    }
    cvReleaseCapture(&capture);
}
```

This one obviously does leak:

```
int main()
{
    CvCapture* capture;
    IplImage* frame;
    IplImage* tmp;

    capture = cvCreateCameraCapture(0);
    while (1) {
       if (capture) {
          frame = cvQueryFrame(capture);
       }
       if (frame) {
          CvSize size = cvSize(100, 100);
          tmp = cvCreateImage(size, IPL_DEPTH_8U, 3);
          cvResize(frame, tmp, CV_INTER_CUBIC);
          // Do some stuff with tmp
       }
    }
    cvReleaseCapture(&capture);
}
```

While this one doesnt leak:

```
int main()
{
    CvCapture* capture;
    IplImage* frame;
    IplImage* tmp;

    capture = cvCreateCameraCapture(0);
    while (1) {
       if (capture) {
          frame = cvQueryFrame(capture);
       }
       if (frame) {
          CvSize size = cvSize(100, 100);
          tmp = cvCreateImage(size, IPL_DEPTH_8U, 3);
          cvResize(frame, tmp, CV_INTER_CUBIC);
          // Do some stuff with tmp

          // release tmp:
          cvReleaseImage(&tmp);
       }
    }
    cvReleaseCapture(&capture);
}
```

Can you try the last example? If it does leak, you probably really have some problems with wrong headers, or linked libraries.

Comment: obivously, since `cvReleaseCapture(&capture)` isnt ever called because of `while(1)` this is some kind of leak too, but memory usage shouldnt increase over time for the last example.

Comment: I've posted additional comments at the top. Your example worked when I ran it as a loop in `main()`, but when it runs in a separate `pthread` the memory leak behavior resumes.

Answer (score 1):

I checked today [01/04/2015], on current wheezy/main repository Dev packages of opencv (apart from gpu) are linked to openCV 2.4.1. Here test steps :

Install packages :

```
sudo apt-get install cmake build-essential libopencv-core-dev libcv-dev libcvaux-dev libhighgui-dev libopencv-calib3d-dev libopencv-contrib-dev libopencv-core-dev libopencv-dev libopencv-features2d-dev libopencv-flann-dev libopencv-highgui-dev libopencv-imgproc-dev libopencv-legacy-dev libopencv-ml-dev libopencv-objdetect-dev libopencv-video-dev
```

Verify openCv libraries installed version  :

```
sudo ldconfig -v | grep opencv
```

Result :

```
libopencv_imgproc.so.2.4 -> libopencv_imgproc.so.2.4.1
libopencv_highgui.so.2.4 -> libopencv_highgui.so.2.4.1
libopencv_legacy.so.2.4 -> libopencv_legacy.so.2.4.1
libopencv_objdetect.so.2.4 -> libopencv_objdetect.so.2.4.1
libopencv_calib3d.so.2.4 -> libopencv_calib3d.so.2.4.1
libopencv_videostab.so.2.4 -> libopencv_videostab.so.2.4.1
libopencv_ml.so.2.4 -> libopencv_ml.so.2.4.1
libopencv_core.so.2.4 -> libopencv_core.so.2.4.1
libopencv_ts.so.2.4 -> libopencv_ts.so.2.4.1
libopencv_stitching.so.2.4 -> libopencv_stitching.so.2.4.1
libopencv_photo.so.2.4 -> libopencv_photo.so.2.4.1
libopencv_flann.so.2.4 -> libopencv_flann.so.2.4.1
libopencv_features2d.so.2.4 -> libopencv_features2d.so.2.4.1
libopencv_video.so.2.4 -> libopencv_video.so.2.4.1
ibopencv_contrib.so.2.4 -> libopencv_contrib.so.2.4.1
```

Test program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>

#include "opencv/cxcore.h"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui_c.h"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc_c.h"

int main(int argc, char * const argv[])
{
    struct rusage usage;
    long max_resident_set_size = 0;
    long frame_no = 0;

    CvCapture* capture;
    IplImage*  frame;
    capture = cvCreateCameraCapture(0);

    if (!capture) {
        // error getting webcam
        return 1;
    }

    //  test 100 frames to check memory usage
    while (frame_no < 100) {
        frame = cvQueryFrame(capture);
        frame_no++;

        errno = 0;
        getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &usage);
        if (errno == EFAULT)
            printf("Error: EFAULT\n");
        else if (errno == EINVAL)
            printf("Error: EINVAL\n");
        else if (max_resident_set_size != usage.ru_maxrss) {

            printf("frame %ld maximum resident set size: %ld\n", frame_no, usage.ru_maxrss);
            printf("frame %ld maximum resident set size diff : %ld\n", frame_no, (usage.ru_maxrss - max_resident_set_size));

            max_resident_set_size = usage.ru_maxrss;
        }
    }

    cvReleaseCapture(&capture);
    return 0;
}
```

I have no memory problem using above code with OpenCV 2.4.

I suggest you uninstall openCV 2.3.1 package, update system and install latest ones and use openCV2 notation.

To list installed packages :

```
sudo dpkg --get-selections | grep -v deinstall | grep cv
```

Hope this help.